# CMD console windows is very slow

Tags: cmd.exe, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 coding in C#. 
In both when I run the solution ctrl + F5 the CMD window takes 15-20 seconds from  total black to show the output of the project.
If I open CMD outside the Visual Studio it will be fast.

and idea what makes so slow ?

Comment: What kind of project is this? A command line program? How long does it run in total? How much output does it produce? Moreover, I guess you added the "Visual-Studio-Code" tag accidentally (do you know what "Visual Studio Code" is and that it is a completely different product than "Visual Studio"?)

Comment: @DocBrown in all projects the waiting time is very very slow, even for "Hello world". btw I fixed the tag and it's a command line.

Comment: Is your "Hello World" program a command line program? Written in which programming language? How precisely do you start it? By pressing "F5" to run it in the debugger? And please, don't bury your clarification here in some comments where they are hard to find, instead use the "edit" button above to improve the question.

Comment: probably it's the antivirus blocking the exe file to check. I've seen that on many PCs